# onChange texfield javascript

Tags: javascript

tenho uma *textfield* com um *id* e quero que no momento que acabo que escrever execute uma ação `onChange` em JavaScript.

```
<input type='text' id='idNewClient' />
```

Parte do JS

```
$("idNewClient").change(function() {
    console.log("teste");
});
```

Tenho sempre um erro "*change is not a function*".

Comment: O fato de estar faltando o "#" no seletor não deveria ser a causa do erro citado. No máximo o evento não seria disparado. Tente usar `$("#idNewClient").on("change", function() {`

Comment: Se com a sugestão acima aparecer o erro "_on is not a function_", aí o problema é outro.

Comment: tem certeza que o `jquery` está carregado? se abrir o *developer tools* e digitar por exemplo `$('teste')` aparece o que?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Creio que se o jQuery não estivesse carregando daria o erro "_$ is not defined_"

Comment: extamente @sam, só pra confirmar se dá erro na página, pode ser até outro script, só pra tirar a dúvida

Comment: Pra ter certeza de que o jQuery está carregado basta checar se `$.fn.jquery` retorna a versão do jQuery. Se retornar está tudo OK, senão é porque o jQuery não foi carregado ou sobrescrito.

Answer (score 2):

Seu seletor jQuery está errado. Está faltando um "#" antes do ID do input.

Com o seguinte código funcionará.

```js
$("#idNewClient").change(function() {
    console.log("teste");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='idNewClient'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o objeto retornado não possui o método [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) significa que este objeto não é um objeto jQuery.

Para checar se a variável `$` é realmente o jQuery você pode checar o conteúdo de [`$.fn.jquery`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/).

Se printar uma string como `"1.12.4"` é porque `$` é o jQuery e a string representa a versão. Mas esse não é o seu caso, pois se fosse não ocorreria o erro citado na pergunta.

OK, descobrimos que `$` não é jQuery, o próximo passo é descobrir se o jQuery foi realmente carregado. Para isso cheque a o conteúdo de `window.jQuery`. Se for `undefined` é muito provável que o jQuery não foi carregado com a página.

A única excessão seria se houvesse algum [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) no seu código. Exemplo:

```
// window.$ não é modificado. Apenas window.jQuery contém a lib
jQuery.noConflict();

// window.$ e window.jQuery não são modificados. Apenas window.jimCarrey contém a lib
let jimCarrey = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Então depois de entender os conceitos acima o passo a passo para descobrir seria:

```
>> $.fn.jquery
"1.12.4"     // OK
>> $.fn.jquery
ReferenceError: $.fn is undefined  // $ não é jQuery

>> jQuery.fn.jquery
"1.12.4"     // OK, apenas $ não é jQuery
>> jQuery.fn.jquery
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  // jQuery não carregado
>> jQuery.fn.jquery
ReferenceError: jQuery.fn is undefined  // jQuery foi sobrescrito
```

Se os testes acima falharem, dê um <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> e pesquise por `jQuery.noConflict` no seu código. Se não achar é porque não está carregado.

**Curiosidade**

Se o jQuery não está carregado como `$('body')` retorna um elemento HTML corretamente quando executo no console do navegador?!?!

Alguns navegadores modernos (como o [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands), o [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?hl=pt-br#selector) e o [Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/command-line#css-selector-string)) usam o `$` como um *alias* para [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) e `$$` como *alias* para [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) casos estes não sejam utilizados pela página carregada.